# Trouble installing psycopg2 on CentOS

Tags: python, postgresql, installation, centos, psycopg2

I'm trying to install psycopg2 on CentOS, I followed everything on this [tutorial](http://thebuild.com/blog/2009/10/17/wordpress-to-djangopostgresql-part-3-installing-apache-python-2-6-psycopg2-and-mod_wsgi/) from "On with it: Installing Python 2.6" all the way to when it imports psycopg2, but when I try to import I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/python2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from _psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
ImportError: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to troubleshoot this?

Comment: This will give the current version installed: python -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__version__)"

Answer (score 25, accepted):

psycopg2 is a python wrapper around the PostgreSQL libraries, so you need those installed on your system too.

Since you're using CentOS, try this from the command line to install the postgre libs.

`yum install postgresql-libs`

Comment: looks like AWS saying "yum doesn't have postgresql-libs" or "-lib"

Comment: CentOS 6.2 says: "No package postgresql-libs available"

Comment: Does this require sudo access or not ?

Comment: @rohitsakala Most likely, yes.

Comment: In CentOs 8.0 you must install another package:
dnf install postgresql-devel

Answer (score 23):

1. Forget your tutorial.
2. [Install EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL/FAQ#howtouse)
3. yum install python-psycopg2

Django [supports Python 2.4](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/) just fine. If you really need Python 2.6 you can also use EPEL (`yum install python26`) - but there's no psycopg2 package for it yet.

Comment: on amz linux at the time of writing this, step 3 is sufficient

Comment: after days of fighting, this was the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I followed the first answer to install python libs:

```
yum install postgresql-lib
```

but it didn't work, so I also did a yum install of the devel and python:

```
yum install postgresql91-devel.x86_64
yum install postgresql91-python.x86_64
```

Not sure which one did it, but my guess is the devel.

Comment: Why the negative comments? INdeed "postgresql-devel" is required!

Comment: @Coaden you should use "postgresql-libs" with a "s" at the end

Comment: yum install postgresql-devel is what I had to do as well on centos 7

Comment: postgresql-libs isn't sufficient. I just tried it. After installing postgresql-devel  it worked.

Comment: For me this is worked: sudo yum install postgresql-devel followed by sudo pip install psycopg2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that `python-psycopg2` disappeared after a PostgreSQL uninstallation and `yum install python-psycopg2` no longer found the package. Here is how I got it installed again.

First, install the `pgdg-redhat` yum repository:

```
yum install -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
```

This will create the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-redhat-all.repo` which lists many repositories (of which most seem to be broken). The only source of `python-psycopg2` seems to be the `pgdg11` repo:

```
[pgdg11]
name=PostgreSQL 11 for RHEL/CentOS $releasever - $basearch
enabled=0
baseurl=https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/11/redhat/rhel-$releasever-$basearch
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG
```

Now you can install the package by explicitly enabling the repository containing the package:

```
yum install python-psycopg2 --enablerepo=pgdg11
```

Answer (score -4):

for ubuntu you'll want

`sudo apt-get install python2.7-psycopg2`

or if using python 3

`sudo apt-get install python3-psycopg2`

Comment: not sure why this got a few down-votes -- was up-voted previously for being useful to other ubuntu users

Comment: likely because plpython is not psycopg2, they are very different things

Comment: also: question is about CentOS, not about Ubuntu.

Comment: currently at -4 -- originally found this through google searching about ubuntu so figured I'd help the next guy -- 1 more comment asking to remove and it's gone... or ask to keep it