# Install python36-psycopg2 on centos Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to install python36-psycopg2 as per the instructions of my lab. I have done the following:

yum install -y postgresql-devel python36-devel python36-psycopg2

but i keep getting the error message:

No package python36-psycopg2 available.
Nothing to do

any ideas why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble installing psycopg2 on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821094/trouble-installing-psycopg2-on-centos)

Comment: Glad you got that solved.